# I am getting fatal error while uploading images in php mysql

Tags: php

I am inputting image in

```
<input type="file" name="uploaded_files[]" id="input_clone" multiple="multiple" />
```

In .php  i am using like this

```
Error: the XML response that was returned from the server is invalid.
Received:
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\olam\classes\class.xajax.php</b> on line <b>1135</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\olam\classes\class.xajax.php:1135) in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\olam\components\xajax\xajax.inc.php</b> on line <b>678</b><br />
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><xjx><cmd n="js"><![CDATA[xajax.loadingFunction();]]></cmd><cmd n="js"><![CDATA[document.location.replace('?p=complete');]]></cmd><cmd n="js"><![CDATA[xajax.doneLoadingFunction();]]></cmd></xjx>
```

```
 echo $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'];
     foreach($_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'] as $key=>$value)
     {
          if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'][$key]) && $_FILES['uploaded_files']['error'][$key] == 0)
          {

                $filename = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'][$key];


                if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'][$key], 'uploads/'. $filename))
                {


                }
                else
                {
                      die ('There was a problem uploading the pictures.');
                }
          }
          else
          {
            die ('There is a problem with the uploading system.');
          }
     }
```

This is giving me fatal error..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+Invalid+argument+supplied+for+foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forgot to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form which is preventing the files from uploading. As a result `$_FILES` is empty and you're getting that error.

Comment: Also he is using `header()` after outputting HTML

Comment: That's just icing on the cake :)

Comment: I am using enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form  my code http://pastebin.com/HWkMSxU4

Comment: uploaded_files  is also a field in mysql table..my php code http://pastebin.com/D1Ug0rJG